# what is mean by scalar value mean in mongoDB while making quety , db.book.find({author:"sam"})

Tags: mongodb, find

[image: this is cousera questuion , what is scalar value mean here]

**what does scalar value mean in this question** ,please make me understand i know what this query does , it not only return the field with single value but also return the array containning this key word

Comment: In this example, scalar means "literal".  In this case the query will only find documents in the collection "Books" where the field "genre" is set to the string literal value "Historical".  The term "Scalar" refers to a simple field value - a value that only has one component to it.  In this example, it is a string.